# FileNotFound Exception when trying to spark submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, filenotfoundexception

I have a spark jar which I am trying to submit to my local spark instance. The jar is packages such that all config files are present in the /resources folder as per the maven structure.

Below is the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Users/prime/Desktop/TibcoMsgConsumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

One observable thing in the above exception is the `!` mark present at the end of the jar: `TibcoMsgConsumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/`

If I remove the spark relevant parts (Java Spark context) from this jar and make it a normal Java Jar, I do not face any issue. What might be wrong here?

I decompiled the class and here is how I load the file:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(this.classLoader.getResource("config.properties").getFile());
  private Properties properties = this.propLoader.initProp(this.file);
```

Here is how I run the job: 
`/spark-submit --conf spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true --verbose --class "ril.bigdata.com.Main" --master local[*]  ~/Desktop/TibcoMsgConsumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever comes after `!` is inside the jar. It is not looking for `config.properties` inside `resources`, it's searching in the root of your JAR.

```
File file = new File(this.classLoader.getResource("resources/config.properties").getFile());
```

This should make it work.

Also, [JavaDoc for getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Comment: I ended up hardcoding the values just to check, all is fine however there are other issues in the app.